# react-vimeo not triggering onPause, onPlay methods

Tags: typescript, next.js, vimeo

I am not being able to trigger any props while playing a Vimeo video on my page. Here's an example of pieces of my attempt:

```
import Vimeo from '@u-wave/react-vimeo';

const handleVimeoProgress = (data: any) => {
    console.log('Progress:', data.percent);
};

<Vimeo
    video="..."
    width="850"
    height="400"
    onProgress={handleVimeoProgress}
    autoplay
/>
```

Version:

```
"@u-wave/react-vimeo": "^0.9.10",
"next": "14.0.3",
```

Video is playing as expected and no issues so far but `handleVimeoProgress` is never being triggered.

Any ideas?